# if javascript statement something wrong

Tags: javascript, html

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <hr>
 <div>

   <div id="myPos">

 </div>


 </div>

  <hr>
  <!--Storing my array -->
  <div id="myArray">

  </div>

  <br>
  <br/>
  <hr>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   var pos=-1;


   function randomSort(a,b){
return(parseInt(Math.random()*10)%2);
     }

   function roll(){
var myGun = new Array();
myGun[0]="First Slot";
myGun[1]="Second Slot";
myGun[2]="Third Slot";
myGun[3]="Fourth Slot";
myGun[4]="Fifth Slot";
myGun[5]="Sixth Slot";
myGun.sort(randomSort).toString();

document.getElementById("myArray").innerHTML="";



for(i=0;i<myGun.length;i++)
{
    document.getElementById("myArray").innerHTML+=myGun[i]+ "<br>"; 
}

    document.getElementById("myPos").innerHTML= "Position:"+ (pos=-1);
     }

function shot(){

    if(pos<myGun.length)
    {
        document.getElementById("myPos").innerHTML="Position:"+ (pos=pos+1) +"<br/>";


   }
    else
    {
       alert("you loose");
    }
       return pos;
}

     </script>

<footer>
    <button id="btnRoll" onclick="roll()">Roll</button>
    <button id="btnShot" onclick="shot()">Shot</button>
</footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's not working about it? Do you get an error? Does it not perform the action that you expected?

Comment: `pos` is not defined anywhere. You might want also to do: 1. give us the entire code 2. Give us the error 3. Work on FF so you actually get meaningful error messages.

Comment: You cannot have this equal statement in the expression. See below:

`document.getElementById("myPos").innerHTML="Position:"+ (++pos) +"<br/>";`

Comment: Please include the error message you are getting or the incorrect behavior you are seeing

Comment: Is this all the code from your function? if yes then are you sure myGun is an array? If not please post your full function if you can..

Comment: **More information => Better answers**.

Comment: You're comparing an integer `pos` to the length of the array, not to a variable within that array?

Comment: @Rolice Yes, you can. The assignment expression is in parens, so it's  OK.

Comment: *"but can't figure out where the error at"* - [see here](http://bighugelabs.com/output/motivator04f48322aa00f413fd071726718a70d3861e3cb6.jpg)

Comment: I agree with @Felix Kling.
@Šime Vidas, this is one line cutting solution :)

@Berti, if you fix this line, and the other mistakes - proper initialization of your variables (global or local - currently you have not supplied any info about `pos` and `myGun`) it would make your code working.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - I get 404 not found on the link.
With a quick debug I think you have to fix there string concatenations like:
`document.getElementById("myPos").innerHTML= "Position:"+ (pos=-1);` to (in this case):
`document.getElementById("myPos").innerHTML= "Position:"+ (--pos);`

The other thing is @Berti has to implement his functions at least in the <head></head> tag in <script>function ...</script>, this might help.

Comment: Is this the whole code, @Berti?

Comment: @Rolice [Try here](http://vidasp.net/errorconsole.jpg) `:)`

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Check my answer :D
Which FF version you use?

Comment: @Rolice Huh? I stopped watching this topic. My image is just a comment on OP's statement where he says that he can't figure out where the error is. That's what the error console is for, and he should check it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out, it worked for me, but I lost. :) I have fixed several minior bugs and made some adjustments to the HTML, which where not the problem. The problem here was the array - which was local variable to the second function, but not to the third - I have made it golobal variable as pos, but reset it in **roll** (your original definition looked it should be reset there).

The first function not need a and b arguments, since it does not use them.
I have moved all the stuff in the  tag of the page, but you can also all script contents it in a separate `.js` file for readability:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="path to file"></script>`.

Tell me if this work for you, too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pos = -1;
        var myGun = new Array;

        function randomSort()
        {
            return parseInt(Math.random() * 10) % 2;
        }

        function roll()
        {
            myGun = [];
            myGun[0]="First Slot";
            myGun[1]="Second Slot";
            myGun[2]="Third Slot";
            myGun[3]="Fourth Slot";
            myGun[4]="Fifth Slot";
            myGun[5]="Sixth Slot";
            myGun.sort(randomSort).toString();

            document.getElementById("myArray").innerHTML = '';



            for(i=0; i < myGun.length; i++)
                document.getElementById("myArray").innerHTML += myGun[i] + "<br />";

            document.getElementById("myPos").innerHTML = "Position:" + (--pos);
        }

        function shot()
        {
            if(pos < myGun.length)
                document.getElementById("myPos").innerHTML = "Position:" + (pos++) + "<br />";
            else
                alert("you loose");

            return pos;
        }

     </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <hr />
    <div>
        <div id="myPos"></div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <!--Storing my array -->
    <div id="myArray">

    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <footer>
        <input type="button" id="btnRoll" onclick="roll()" value="Roll" />
        <input type="button" id="btnShot" onclick="shot()" value="Shot" />
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked fine and i agree, sorry for sending spaguetti code ... now its much more readable. I just had to change some logic at the if shot function statement, and at the for roll function. At the shot() you had to write "Position:" + (++pos) ... otherwise i had to press twice btnShot to add. Anyway this worked fine. Thanks again. Also i will get out the script to a .js file as you suggest to keep things clean.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function shot(){
        if(pos>=myGun.length)
        {
            pos = pos +1;
            document.getElementById("myPos").innerHTML="Position:"+ pos +"<br/>";

       }
        else
        {
           alert("you loose");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace ">=" by "<":

```
if( pos < myGun.length ) { ...
```

That said, you are also using global variables which is not recommended.

A better way to write this function would be:

```
function shot( pos, myGun ) {
  if ( pos < myGun.length ) {
    document.getElementById( "myPos" ).innerHTML="Position:"+ ++pos + "<br/>";
  } else {
    alert( "you loose" );
  }
  return pos;
}
```

Note that the function returns the updated pos, after increment.

Comment: He wants to 'alert if pos is more than myGun,' your use of the `<` operator does the opposite of that.

Comment: @David: Except that the alert in the code is in the `else` statement. Not sure if OP has it backward though. Seems odd to describe the else as the desired result.

Comment: @Patrick: yeah, that's what confused me. I read the code, saw the comment and then forgot the code. Long day >.<

Comment: @David, the proposed change will alert if pos >= myGun.length because the alert is in the else statement.

Comment: @Jean, yeah; Patrick (kindly) pointed that out to me in his comment. I can only apologise for being an idiot...sorry! >.<